# Homology for virtual knot diagram

Tags: homology-cohomology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am studying now the article of V. O. Manturov about free knots ("*Free Knots and Parity*", https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.5348.pdf). I got stuck on the section "*Parity as homology*" (p.6), at the homology group $H_1(\Gamma,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. I don't know how, is it defined? Thought first that this is simply the homology of the graph understood as a 1-dimensional CW-complex. With this definition, I don't know, however, how to interpret this sentence:

> *"The homology group $H_1(\Gamma,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is generated by
>   "halves" corresponding to vertices: for every vertex $v$ we have two
>   halves of the graph $\Gamma_{v,1}$ and $\Gamma_{v,2}$, obtained by
>   smoothing at this vertex".*